# Searching an inventory stored within a vector based upon user input

Tags: c++, vector, binary-search

I was asked to write a search inventory function that will search the vector made based on its model, and return to the user, its index position. I can't for the life of me figure out how to do this with vectors other than an array. Please help!

```
//this function will search the inventory and return its index position.        
void searchInventory(vector<Vehicle> &vehicles)
{
    int invSize = vehicles.size();
    string vModel;
    int position = -1;
    int index = 0; //position of search
    bool found = false; //flag

cout << "Please enter the model number of the vehicle you are searching for: " << endl;
getline(cin, vModel);

while (index < invSize && !found)
{
    if (vehicles[index].getModel == vModel)
    {
        found = true;
        position = index;
    }
       index++;
}
  return position;
  cin.ignore();

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the first thing to do is format your code nicely.

Next the return type is wrong. You are returning an `int` but the return type of the function is `void`. Also your comment is not quite correct. If you don't find any value you return a value one past the end of the vector (which is a common practice in C++ but you should mention it).

```
void searchInventory(vector<Vehicle> &vehicles)
```

There are a couple of ways of looping through a vector.

```
while (index < invSize && !found) {
       // STUFF
       index++;
}
```

or

```
for(int index = 0; index < invSize && !found; ++index) {
     // STUFF
}
```

or

```
for(auto loop = std::begin(vehicles); loop != std::end(vehicles); ++loop) {
    // STUFF
}
```

or

```
for(auto const& item: vehicles) {
    // STUFF
}
```

There are also some standard functions to search containers.

```
std::find(std::begin(vehicles), std::end(vehicles), /*Test*/);
```

Once you have it working it may be worth getting more advice at [code review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com)

Comment: It was my very first time placing a question on here so my code is a little off. Thank you for your comments though! I am still just struggling with how to return the "index position"

Comment: @That1GirlProgrammer: You did that just fine with `return position;` The index is just the offset into the array where the data is located.

Answer (score 0):

Your function's return type is void but you are returning an integer.

Also, FYI nothing after the return statement will be executed, so `cin.ignore()` is not used here.

Hint for the future: some of the function is indented and the rest isn't, which makes it harder to figure out initially. Taking the effort to fully format the code before posting is worth the effort.